# django - see the debug error on the server

Tags: python, django

In django with the `DEBUG` set to true when you POST and something is wrong, you'll see the error message as a webpage with sufficient details. But this is on the client side (browser). Is there a way to see the same error on the server?

We have a mobile application which POSTs to the server and doesn't have access to log or browser. Can I catch the error it gets on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your settings.py:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s [%(asctime)s] %(module)s %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

the console will show the error details

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/error-reporting/

Any time an error is raised, you can get an email or write to a file, with the information about the error.